# Group and add variable of type stock and another type in a single step?

Tags: r, dplyr, summarize

I want to group  by district summing 'incoming' values at quarter and get the value of the 'stock' in the last quarter (3) in **just one step.** 'stock' can not summed through quarters.
My example dataframe:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame ("district"= rep(c("ARA", "BJI", "CMC"), each=3),
                  "quarter"=rep(1:3,3),
                  "incoming"= c(4044, 2992, 2556, 1639, 9547, 1191,2038,1942,225),
                  "stock"= c(19547,3160, 1533,5355,6146,355,5816,1119,333)
                  )
df

  district quarter incoming stock
1      ARA       1     4044 19547
2      ARA       2     2992  3160
3      ARA       3     2556  1533
4      BJI       1     1639  5355
5      BJI       2     9547  6146
6      BJI       3     1191   355
7      CMC       1     2038  5816
8      CMC       2     1942  1119
9      CMC       3      225   333
```

The actual dataframe has ~45.000 rows and 41 variables of which 8 are of type stock.

The result should be:

```
# A tibble: 3 × 3
  district stock incoming
  <chr>    <dbl>    <dbl>
1 ARA       1533     9592
2 BJI        355    12377
3 CMC        333     4205
```

I know how to get to the result but in **three steps** and I don't think it's efficient and error prone due to the data.

My approach:

```
basea <- df %>% 
  group_by(district) %>% 
  filter(quarter==3) %>% #take only the last quarter
  summarise(across(stock, sum)) %>% 
 
baseb <- df %>% 
  group_by(district) %>% 
  summarise(across(incoming, sum)) %>% 

final <- full_join(basea, baseb)
```

Does anyone have any suggestions to perform the procedure in one (or at least two) steps?
Grateful,
Modus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that the dataset only has 3 quarters and not 4. If that's not the case use `nth(3)` instead of `last()`

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  group_by(district) %>%  
  summarise(stock = last(stock), 
            incoming = sum(incoming))

# A tibble: 3 × 3
  district stock incoming
  <chr>    <dbl>    <dbl>
1 ARA       1533     9592
2 BJI        355    12377
3 CMC        333     4205
```

Comment: Thanks, sometimes we fail to see the simplest solutions.

Answer (score 2):

here is a `data.table` approach

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(incoming = sum(incoming), stock = stock[.N]), by = .(district)]

   district incoming stock
1:      ARA     9592  1533
2:      BJI    12377   355
3:      CMC     4205   333
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a refactor that removes some of the duplicated code. This also seems like a prime use-case for creating a custom function that can be QC'd and maintained easier:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame ("district"= rep(c("ARA", "BJI", "CMC"), each=3),
                  "quarter"=rep(1:3,3),
                  "incoming"= c(4044, 2992, 2556, 1639, 9547, 1191,2038,1942,225),
                  "stock"= c(19547,3160, 1533,5355,6146,355,5816,1119,333)
)

aggregate_stocks <- function(df, n_quarter) {
  
  base <- df %>% 
    group_by(district)
  
  basea <- base %>% 
    filter(quarter == n_quarter) %>% 
    summarise(across(stock, sum)) 
  
  baseb <- base %>% 
    summarise(across(incoming, sum)) 
  
  final <- full_join(basea, baseb, by = "district")
  
  return(final)
  
}

aggregate_stocks(df, 3)
#> # A tibble: 3 × 3
#>   district stock incoming
#>   <chr>    <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1 ARA       1533     9592
#> 2 BJI        355    12377
#> 3 CMC        333     4205
```

Comment: Thanks for the function idea.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the same solution as @Tom Hoel but without using a function to subset, instead just use `[]`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(district) %>% 
  summarise(stock = stock[3],
            incoming = sum(incoming))
```

```
district stock incoming
  <chr>    <dbl>    <dbl>
1 ARA       1533     9592
2 BJI        355    12377
3 CMC        333     4205
```